# How do I use a Javascript keyword as a variable name?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

If I want to use the following in JS, Is some option available to do it?

```
var break = "";
```

In C# we have the option to use it using @, is similar option available in JS

```
public int @public;
```

Comment: You don't, for obvious reasons. And no, there's no way to use *reserved* keywords as variable names, and why would you, you have an infinite number of other choices than the few reserved words.

Comment: Just use another character in front of it, like a `$` or `_`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if you insist, you can

```
var $break = 1;
```

which is the same as C# in terms of characters ;)

Seriously, you cannot use reserved keywords as variables, but they are allowed as property names:

```
myObj = {}
myObj.break = 'whatever';
```

Also, do note that the repertoire of the reserved words varies depending on the strictness. For example,

```
var interface = 1;
```

is valid in the non-strict mode, but breaks once you add `use strict` to your script.

Comment: I think it is important to mention that `global` variables are properties of `window`(In Browser context)

Comment: @Rayon but you still can't use them with global variable syntax: `window["break"] = 42;` is ok, but you can't use it as `if (break == 44)` even for all reasonable names you can.

Comment: Thanks for you idea @Georg

Answer (score 4):

You can't use Javascript keywords as a variable name.